# How to adjust the output table generated in a shiny code

Tags: r, shiny

How to adjust the output table generated in my shiny code? I'll insert an image for you to see, in addition to leaving the executable code below. From the image you can see that it went beyond the limits of the page, and it got ugly. Is there any way to adjust this?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-01",
                                         "2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-01")),
                      date2 = as.Date(c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-04","2022-01-05","2022-01-06",
                                        "2022-01-07","2022-01-08","2022-01-09","2022-01-10")), 
                      Id = c("1", "2", "3", "4","5","6","7","8","9","10"),
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "DEF", "ABC","GHI","JKL","MNO","MRO","ANO","PNO"), 
                      coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1,6,4,3,6,6,5),
                      DR=c(1,4,3,2,9,10,2,1,10,9),
                      DR0=c(4,5,6,8,9,10,12,9,10,9),
                      DR01=c(4,5,3,8,2,10,12,9,3,9),
                      DR02=c(4,5,3,8,2,10,12,9,3,9),
                      DR03=c(4,5,3,8,2,10,12,9,3,9),
                      DR04=c(4,5,3,8,2,10,12,9,3,9),
                      DR05=c(4,5,3,8,2,10,12,9,3,9),
                      DR06=c(4,5,3,8,2,10,12,9,3,9),
                      DR07=c(4,5,3,8,2,10,12,9,3,9),
                      DR08=c(4,5,3,8,2,10,12,9,3,9),
                      DR09=c(4,5,3,8,2,10,12,9,3,9),
                      DR010=c(4,5,3,8,2,10,12,9,3,9)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -10L))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange'),
                                 br()
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table')
                                 
                               )
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   min = min(data()$date2),
                   max = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    req(input$daterange1[1] <= input$daterange1[2])
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    Test <- subset(data(), as.Date(date2) %in% days)
            
   
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
  
  datatable (data_subset(),options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
                                          paging =TRUE,searching = FALSE, pageLength =  10,dom = 'tip',scrollx=T),
             rownames = FALSE) 
})
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `datatable` options, it's `scrollX` and not `scrollx`, change that and you get your desired output.

```
output$table <- renderDataTable({
    datatable (
      data_subset(),
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),
        paging = TRUE, 
        searching = FALSE, 
        pageLength =  10,
        dom = 'tip',
        scrollX = TRUE
      ),
      rownames = FALSE
    ) 
  })
```